# How can I find the largest (in size) of two integer types?

Tags: c++

For instance:

```
template <typename Type1, typename Type2>
void fun(const Type1 &v1, const Type2 &v2)
{
    largest<Type1, Type2>::type val = v1 + v2;
    .
    .
    .
};
```

I'd like to know if there's a "largest" somewhere, perhaps in boost.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357629/how-do-you-find-the-range-of-values-that-integer-types-can-represent-in-c

Comment: You can also use the `uac_type` template of this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998571/c-template-for-safe-integer-casts/998982#998982 . Pass in the different types, and get back the type of the result the compiler would choose.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
template<bool, typename T1, typename T2>
struct is_cond {
    typedef T1 type;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct is_cond<false, T1, T2> {
    typedef T2 type;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct largest {
     typedef typename is_cond< (sizeof(T1)>sizeof(T2)), T1, T2>::type type;
};
```

Comment: How will you compare unsigned int to int?  There's both the same size.

Comment: He specified 'in size' not in range, so I guess both the same size is the answer.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: OK, OK. Why repeat twice? I inserted `;` as you wish.

Comment: @wheaties: To answer your question I need to know what type is larger in the OP's opinion. In the OP's question this is unkonown.

Comment: Still doesn't work IMHO. For example,  largest <int,double> d; cout << sizeof(d) << endl; should print 8, I think. It prints 1.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: `largest <int,double>::type d; cout << sizeof(d) << endl;` prints 8. Attention! `largest <int,double>::type` rather than `largest <int,double>`

Comment: I'm only interested int signed integral types, so this does it. Thanks Alexey!

Comment: Notice that the selected type is no necessarily identical to the result of the addition. For instance `char` + `short` = `int` on nowaday's machines, but you will select short (nothing bad - just want to note that)

Comment: Yes, it's actually for another use, this was just an example. But thanks for the remark.

Comment: This would be cleaner using `boost::mpl::if_` instead of a home grown `is_cond`.

Comment: Yes, boost::mpl::if_c is the one.

Answer (score 3):

There is no simple answer.  If the largest type on your machine is a long and the two types passed are an unsigned long and a signed long, what type would you expect val to be?  If unsigned you run the risk of a negative number which will not fit in it.  If signed, you may overflow but still have a number that would fit in the unsigned number space.

If these limitations are acceptable you could use Alexey Malistov's approach, but the resulting type if Type1 and Type2 are the same size but different types will be different depending on the order the values are passed.

Take a look at the boost mpl function [if_](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/if.html), with which you can pick one of two types.  You'll need need to come up with your own rules for how to pick the resulting type.

Comment: Even though he's only interested in specific types (signed integral) I'm glad you brought this up.

Comment: You're right. The integrals should both be signed or unsigned. In my case I'm interested in signed ones, but your remark is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This won't be very feasible.  How do you tell the difference between unsigned int and int?  You can't use sizeof() because they're both the same "size" in the memory.  I think you'll have to roll your own template specialization to handle those cases at which point I'd suggest just using an overloaded function.

Comment: Since he asked for largest (in size), I don't think that's a problem.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)  See stephen's answer which is more in depth than mine.

Comment: You're right. The integrals should both be signed or unsigned. In my case I'm interested in signed ones, but your remark is correct.

Answer (score -1):

You probably could roll your own with `sizeof`.

http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/keywords/sizeof

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `sizeof` built-in function of c to get the memory size of the type.  You can also call it on an instance of a type.  For example:

`return (sizeof(v1) > sizeof(v2));`