# Determining largest sizeof() in boost variant

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, boost-mpl, boost-variant

Given:

```
boost::variant<T1,T2,T3,...,TN>
```

Calculate the following at compile time:

```
max(sizeof(T1), sizeof(T2), sizeof(T3),... ,sizeof(TN))
```

I had no idea how to approach this, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953082/how-can-i-find-the-largest-in-size-of-two-integer-types/1953137#1953137) answer shed some light on how I might get started. Using the code in that answer with two types, `T1` and `T2`, I could use the following in a source file to get the size of the larger object:

```
size_t largestSize = sizeof(largest<T1, T2>::type);
```

This is exactly what I'd like to do, but I need the `largest` template to work with more than two classes - specifically, it would need to check all types stored in a `boost::variant` object.

I know that `boost::variant` has a `types` typedef, which defines some sort of list of types in the variant. The problem is, I get totally lost when I try to wrap my head around all the `boost::mpl` stuff in the implementation. I don't intuitively understand what `boost::variant::types` *is*, and how I might be able to pass it into my own template that does something with it.

In my head, this is what the final implementation might look like:

```
typedef boost::variant<T1, T2, T3, T4> MyVariant;
size_t largestSize = sizeof(largest<MyVariant::types>::type);
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to go about implementing this version of `largest`.

I'm not sure if this is a reasonable approach, so I'm open to any other ways to accomplish this (maybe apply a `boost::static_visitor` to all types at compile time?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just ignore the mpl stuff. Start with:

```
template <class T> struct max_variant_sizeof;

template <class... Ts>
struct max_variant_sizeof<boost::variant<Ts...>> {
    static constexpr size_t value = variadic_max(sizeof(Ts)...);
};
```

Now `max_variant_sizeof<MyVariant>::value` will forward all the sizes of all the types to a function. All you need to do is write that `variadic_max`:

```
constexpr size_t variadic_max(size_t v) { return v; }

template <class... Args>
constexpr size_t variadic_max(size_t a, size_t b, Args... cs)
{
    return variadic_max(std::max(a, b), cs...);
}
```

Before C++14, `std::max()` isn't `constexpr`, so that can be replaced with:

```
    return variadic_max((a > b ? a : b), cs...);
```

---

One thing worth noting about:

> maybe apply a `boost::static_visitor` to all types at compile time?

Visitation with a `variant` is a *runtime* operation - your visitor gets called with the type that the `variant` happens to be holding on to. It will not be called with *all* the types.

Comment: I went with this solution, but during my testing I noticed that this won't compile with GCC 4.8.2 or clang 3.5.0 and older, while Wojciech's answer below compiles with GCC 4.7.3 and clang 3.0. I also noticed that neither solution compiles with MSVC19. None of this really matters in the context of the question, but it might be useful for someone stumbling across this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could also change the code from the link you attached to:

```
template <class First, class... Args>
struct largest: largest<First, typename largest<Args...>::type> {
};

template<bool, typename T1, typename T2>
struct is_cond {
    typedef T1 type;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct is_cond<false, T1, T2> {
    typedef T2 type;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct largest<T1, T2> {
     typedef typename is_cond< (sizeof(T1)>sizeof(T2)), T1, T2>::type type;
};
```

Then the usage could look like:

```
cout << sizeof(largest<int, char, double>::type) << endl;
```

**Edit:**

To make it work with boost::variant as well as any other variadic args templated class just add another specialization:

```
template <template <class...> class Var, class... Args>
struct largest<Var<Args...>>: largest<Args...> { };
```

Then usage could look e.g. (with tuple, that can be successfully changed to boost::variant):

```
cout << sizeof(largest<tuple<int, char, double>>::type) << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have using the `boost::mpl` library as a generic library for compile time code operations.

Some header code preparation:

```
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/max_element.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/transform_view.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/sizeof.hpp>

#include <boost/type_traits/alignment_of.hpp>

// alignof_ headers
#include <boost/mpl/size_t.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/aux_/na_spec.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/aux_/lambda_support.hpp>

// alignof mpl style implementation (namespace injection) the same way as the `mpl::sizeof_` did
namespace boost {
namespace mpl {
    template<
        typename BOOST_MPL_AUX_NA_PARAM(T)
    >
    struct alignof_
        : mpl::size_t< boost::alignment_of<T>::value >
    {
        BOOST_MPL_AUX_LAMBDA_SUPPORT(1, alignof_, (T))
    };

    BOOST_MPL_AUX_NA_SPEC_NO_ETI(1, alignof_)
}
}
```

'

Some helper macro:

```
// generates compilation error and shows real type name (and place of declaration in some cases) in an error message, useful for debugging boost::mpl recurrent types

// old C++ standard compatible
//#define UTILITY_TYPE_LOOKUP_BY_ERROR(type_name) \
//    (*(::utility::type_lookup<type_name >::type*)0).operator ,(*(::utility::dummy*)0)

// can be applied in a class, but requires `decltype` support
#define UTILITY_TYPE_LOOKUP_BY_ERROR(type_name) \
    typedef decltype((*(::utility::type_lookup<type_name >::type*)0).operator ,(*(::utility::dummy*)0)) _type_lookup_t

namespace utility
{
    struct dummy {};

    template <typename T>
    struct type_lookup
    {
        typedef T type;
    };
}
```

'

Usage example:

```
namespace mpl = bost::mpl;

typedef mpl::vector<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5> storage_types_t;

typedef typename mpl::deref<
    typename mpl::max_element<
        mpl::transform_view<storage_types_t, mpl::sizeof_<mpl::_1> >
    >::type
>::type max_size_t; // type has stored max sizeof(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)

typedef typename mpl::deref<
    typename mpl::max_element<
        mpl::transform_view<storage_types_t, mpl::alignof_<mpl::_1> >
    >::type
>::type max_alignment_t; // type has stored max alignof(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)

// testing on real values
UTILITY_TYPE_LOOKUP_BY_ERROR(max_size_t);
UTILITY_TYPE_LOOKUP_BY_ERROR(max_alignment_t);
```

'

Visual Studio 2015 error output:

```
error C2039: ',': is not a member of 'boost::mpl::size_t<**calculated max sizeof here**>'
error C2039: ',': is not a member of 'boost::mpl::size_t<**calculated max alignment here**>'
```